# Why does my singleton class throw a StackOverflowerror?

Tags: java, singleton, stack-overflow

I have been writing a program. Everything is in program is controlled by the 'Engine' class. I have hence made it a singleton. Here is my current code that runs just fine.

```
    package org.bautista.cybersafe.core;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.bautista.cybersafe.ui.MainUI;
import org.bautista.cybersafe.util.Cache;
import org.bautista.cybersafe.util.Config;
import org.bautista.cybersafe.util.account.Account;
import org.bautista.cybersafe.util.account.AccountManager;
import org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.User;
import org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.UserManager;

public class Engine {
    private static Engine instance;
    private AccountManager accountManager;
    private final MainUI ui;
    private final UserManager userManager;
    private final Config config;
    private User currentUser;

    private Engine() {
        instance = this; //THIS IS LINE 22
        if (!Cache.cacheExists()) {
            if (!Cache.createCache()) {
                System.out.println("Error creating cache.");
            }
        }
        config = new Config();
        userManager = new UserManager();
        ui = new MainUI();
    }

    public static Engine getInstance() {
        return instance == null ? instance = new Engine() : instance;
    }

    public void setCurrentUser(User user) {
        currentUser = user;
    }

    public User getCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }

    public AccountManager getAccountManager() {
        return accountManager;
    }

    public Config getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public UserManager getUserManager() {
        return userManager;
    }

    public void logOut() {
        currentUser = null;
        accountManager = null;
        ui.showLogin();
    }

    public void openAccountViewer(final Account account) {
        ui.showAccount(account);
        ui.setTitle("Cyber Safe - [" + currentUser.getUsername() + "] -"
                + account.getName());
    }

    public void openCreateAccountScreen() {
        ui.showCreateAccount();
    }

    public void openCreateUserScreen() {
        ui.showCreateUser();
    }

    public void openLoginScreen() {
        ui.showLogin();
        ui.setTitle("Cyber Safe");
    }

    public void openSafeScreen() {
        if (accountManager == null) {
            accountManager = new AccountManager(currentUser);
        }
        ui.showSafe();
        ui.setTitle("Cyber Safe - [" + currentUser.getUsername() + "]");
    }

    public void refreshUI() {
        ui.refresh();
    }

    public void updateAccountPreviews() {
        ui.updateAccountScroller();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> ui.setVisible(true));
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

When I comment out line 22

```
instance = this;
```

I receive a StackOverflowerror. When I debug the program I find that the Engine constructor is being called repeatedly, as if it were performing recursion, until I final get the error. Why does that happen? Should't my #getInstance() method be initiating instance as a new instance of the 'Engine' class?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.InputStream.<init>(InputStream.java:45)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:123)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.Config.loadProperties(Config.java:67)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.Config.<init>(Config.java:29)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.core.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:28)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.core.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:34)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.UserManager.loadUsers(UserManager.java:73)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:20)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.core.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:29)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.core.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:34)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.UserManager.loadUsers(UserManager.java:73)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:20)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.core.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:29)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.core.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:34)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.UserManager.loadUsers(UserManager.java:73)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:20)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.core.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:29)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.core.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:34)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.UserManager.loadUsers(UserManager.java:73)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:20)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.core.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:29)
```

[And here is the full project on Github](https://github.com/Bautista-Baiocchi-lora/Cyber-Safe)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are new Engines being created in any of the other classes that compose your Engine class?

Comment: It is not possible, the constructor is private. Almost every class calls the Engine.getInstance() method. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Show your stacktrace please.

Comment: Oddly enough, the error says it's coming from another class but not commenting out line 22 is the only thing that fixes it. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Added everything needed @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: So, what does UserManager lines 20 and 73 do?

Comment: Calls Engine.getInstance(). I put a link to the project under the stack trace if you would like to look.

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code does not seem to be minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack trace shows the following loop:

```
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.UserManager.loadUsers(UserManager.java:73)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.util.user.UserManager.<init>(UserManager.java:20)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.core.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:29)
at org.bautista.cybersafe.core.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:34)
```

`Engine.getInstance()` calls `new Engine()`.
`new Engine()` calls `new UserManager()`.
`new UserManager()` calls `UserManager.loadUsers()`.
`UserManager.loadUsers()` calls `Engine.getInstance()`, but `Engine.instance` hasn't been assigned yet, since the previous `new Engine()` call hasn't returned yet.

This is why assigning `Engine.instance` in the constructor, before it calls `new UserManager()`, fixes the problem.

You should reorganize your code to prevent that initialization loop. `UserManager` and `Engine` should not be co-dependent during initialization.

Note that doing `private static Engine instance = new Engine()` as suggested in another answer will not fix your initialization loop.

Comment: This is it. Well spotted!

Comment: Thank you very much! I will go ahead and re-write it:)